# Send CPU usage information from mininet hosts to Opendaylight Controller

Tags: load-balancing, cpu-usage, mininet, opendaylight

I am implementing a load balancing application in OpenDaylight. So I need the Cpu utilization of hosts created using Mininet. I want the hosts to send their CPU usage info to the controller at regular intervals.

What is best way achieve this ?

Thanks !